# What is the right way to store users in the bot framework for proactive messaging?

Tags: bots, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a facebook bot where I am trying to send alerts based on some criteria the user has set. I am using Redis Store to store the sessions which I think don't store the user ids permanently. My current code looks like this

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    var botId = message.address.bot.id;
    if (message.membersAdded && message.membersAdded.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < message.membersAdded.length; i++) {
            if (message.membersAdded[i].id === botId) {
                // Say hello
                var isGroup = message.address.conversation.isGroup;
                var txt = isGroup ? "Hello everyone!" : "Hello...";
                var reply = new builder.Message()
                    .address(message.address)
                    .text(txt);
                bot.send(reply);
            }
        }

    } else if (message.membersRemoved) {
        // See if bot was removed

        for (var i = 0; i < message.membersRemoved.length; i++) {
            if (message.membersRemoved[i].id === botId) {
                // Say goodbye
                var reply = new builder.Message()
                    .address(message.address)
                    .text("Goodbye");
                bot.send(reply);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});

bot.on('contactRelationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.action === 'add') {
        var name = message.user ? message.user.name : null;
        var reply = new builder.Message()
            .address(message.address)
            .text("Hello %s... Thanks for adding me.", name || 'there');
        bot.send(reply);
    }
});
```

1. Which method above should I use to add user id to the database. They both seem to solve the same purpose
2. Assuming I manage to get through the above problem, how do I remove users who have blocked my bot from the database while messaging them proactively?

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is the one indicated in your title:

> What is the right way to store users in the bot framework for
> proactive messaging?

You should store the user only when they accept being notified, so in a specific method. Same for unsubscribe: these actions should not be taken during a special event of the bot like `conversationUpdate`  or `contactRelationUpdate` .

If you still want to registrer information during the 1st discussion with the user, have a look to [this first run sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-handle-conversation-events?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#add-a-first-run-dialog)

---

Then to help you about your question of the difference between those 2 events, they depend on the channel:

- `conversationUpdate`:

> Indicates that the bot was added to a conversation, other members were
> added to or removed from the conversation, or conversation metadata
> has changed.

It is thrown at least on the following channels: `emulator`, `webchat`

- `contactRelationUpdate`:

> Indicates that the bot was added or removed from a user's contact
> list.

You will find this event for example in Skype when you add the bot to your contacts

Comment: thanks for the answer but i was wondering how some bots manage to reach every user who has said hi atleast once, surely they must be storing every user's id in a database right? any suggestions on what would be the best entry point for this?

Comment: As indicated each event is triggered on different cases so it will depend on your target channel. Is it only Facebook messenger (as you added this tag)?

Comment: since you seem to have built a couple of bots yourself, how are you storing ids in your bots so far for proactive messaging if you don't mind sharing

Comment: Chatfuel solves this problem in a very simple manner but I am quite curious for custom platforms like Messenger

Comment: I'm not developing in Node.js, but as I said when I want to implement a proactive message I'm storing the information when I have asked the user if (s)he is ok with it, so it's not like your case. I made an edit to my answer to do what your want on the 1st message, regardless of the channel